# How can I search in a post list by section angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of posts with some properties, like this:

```
[
{
"ID": "2",
"ID_user": "6",
"NameUser": "Ary",
"image": "/images/users/ary.jpg",
"creationDate": "2016-05-16 00:00:00",
"lastEditDate": "2016-05-24 14:19:18",
"section": [
  {
    "section": "Front Page",
    "ID_sect": "10"
  }
]
},
{
"ID": "17",
"ID_user": "1",
"NameUser": "dev",
"image": "/images/users/dev.jpg",
"creationDate": "2016-05-18 10:44:38",
"lastEditDate": "2016-05-24 14:58:16",
"section": [
  {
    "section": "Front C",
    "ID_sect": "13"
  }
]}
```

I have checkboxes of the sections. When I check any section I need that it show only the posts with the selected section. The checkboxes are:

```
<ul class="filterlist" >
        <li ng-repeat="section in sections">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sectionCB" value="{{section.ID}}">{{section.name}}</input>
        </li>
</ul>
```

And when I show the posts:

```
<tr class="dashboardTr" ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:sectionCB | filter:search>
        <td id="checkboxColumn"><input type="checkbox" name="actions" class="actions" id="{{post.ID}}"
                                       value="{{post.ID}}" ng-model="post.Selected">
        </td>

        <td id="titleColumn"><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </td>

        <td id="sectionColumn">
            <select class="form-control sectionsClass" id="sectionsSelect-{{post.ID}}" ng-change="updateSection(sectionsModel,this)"
                    ng-model="sectionsModel" >
                <option ng-repeat="section in sections" id="option-{{section.ID}}">{{section.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
</tr>
```

The search filter is for another filter that works. When I write something in a input type=text, it works and filter by the written text.

I did that filter:

```
app.filter('bySection', function(){
return function(posts, start){
    var out = [];
    var sections = $('input[name="sections"]:checked');
    if(sections.length == 0)
        return posts;
    for(var i = 0; i<sections.length; i++){
        if(sections[i] == posts.section)
            out.push(posts);
    }

    return out;
}
});
```

I need to filter by section and it doesn't work
Thank you!

Comment: Did not understand ...if everything is working fine than what is your question??

Comment: @Moumit No no, I need to filter by section, and it doesn't work

Comment: [Create a minimum viable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) working plnkr to demonstrate the problem